# Como faço para armazenar 2 consultas SQL em uma única variável?

Tags: laravel

Boa tarde pessoal, estou tentando fazer 2 consultas em minha aplicação  e quero que ambas sejam armazenadas em uma única variável, tem como fazer ? se sim como faço ?

Consulta 1:

```
$usuarios = DB::table('users')
    ->join('user_municipios', 'user_municipios.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->join('municipios', 'municipios.id', '=', 'user_municipios.municipio_id')
    ->join('perfis', 'perfis.id', '=', 'users.perfil_id')
    ->select('users.id', 'users.municipio_id', 'users.name', 'users.minicurriculo','users.fotoPerfil', 'users.plano_id', 'perfis.perfil', 'municipios.municipio', 'municipios.uf')
    ->where('user_municipios.municipio_id', '=', $municipio_id)->orderBy('users.plano_id', 'DESC')
    ->inRandomOrder()->paginate(25);
```

Consulta 2:

```
$usuarios = DB::table('users')->where('users.municipio_id', '=', $municipio_id)
    ->join('municipios', 'municipios.id', '=', 'users.municipio_id')
    ->join('perfis', 'perfis.id', '=', 'users.perfil_id')
    ->select('users.id', 'users.municipio_id', 'users.name', 'users.minicurriculo','users.fotoPerfil', 'users.plano_id', 'perfis.perfil', 'municipios.municipio', 'municipios.uf')
    ->orderBy('users.plano_id', 'DESC')->inRandomOrder()->paginate(25);
```

Comment: Porque você não coloca um Or na where?

Comment: Não funcionou, porque a segunda consulta 1 da um join na tabela user_municipios e na consulta 2 não.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faz um [`UNION`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#unions) no [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent) já visto que pelo seu código os campos retornadas são os mesmos e as duas consultas ficariam com essas alterações:

```
$usuarios1 = DB::table('users')
    ->join('user_municipios', 'user_municipios.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->join('municipios', 'municipios.id', '=', 'user_municipios.municipio_id')
    ->join('perfis', 'perfis.id', '=', 'users.perfil_id')
    ->select('users.id', 'users.municipio_id', 'users.name', 
             'users.minicurriculo','users.fotoPerfil', 
             'users.plano_id', 'perfis.perfil', 
             'municipios.municipio', 'municipios.uf')
    ->where('user_municipios.municipio_id', '=', $municipio_id);    


$usuarios = DB::table('users')->where('users.municipio_id', '=', $municipio_id)
    ->join('municipios', 'municipios.id', '=', 'users.municipio_id')
    ->join('perfis', 'perfis.id', '=', 'users.perfil_id')
    ->select('users.id', 'users.municipio_id', 'users.name', 
             'users.minicurriculo','users.fotoPerfil', 
             'users.plano_id', 'perfis.perfil', 
             'municipios.municipio', 'municipios.uf')
    ->orderBy('users.plano_id', 'DESC') 
    ->inRandomOrder()
    ->union($usuarios1); //juntando as duas consultas ...
    ->get(25);
```

mas, essa forma o `paginate` que você precisa não funciona, por causa da geração peculiar de SQL que é feita por esse método, mas, existe uma forma para contornar isso:

```
$usuarios1 = DB::table('users')
    ->join('user_municipios', 'user_municipios.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->join('municipios', 'municipios.id', '=', 'user_municipios.municipio_id')
    ->join('perfis', 'perfis.id', '=', 'users.perfil_id')
    ->select('users.id', 'users.municipio_id', 'users.name', 
             'users.minicurriculo','users.fotoPerfil', 
             'users.plano_id', 'perfis.perfil', 
             'municipios.municipio', 'municipios.uf')
    ->where('user_municipios.municipio_id', '=', $municipio_id);   


$usuarios = DB::table('users')->where('users.municipio_id', '=', $municipio_id)
    ->join('municipios', 'municipios.id', '=', 'users.municipio_id')
    ->join('perfis', 'perfis.id', '=', 'users.perfil_id')
    ->select('users.id', 'users.municipio_id', 'users.name', 
             'users.minicurriculo','users.fotoPerfil', 
             'users.plano_id', 'perfis.perfil', 
             'municipios.municipio', 'municipios.uf')
    ->orderBy('users.plano_id', 'DESC') 
    ->inRandomOrder()
    ->union($usuarios1);
```

---

Agora com a união na variável `$usuarios` faça o seguinte:

```
$sql = $usuarios->toSql();
$res = \DB::table(\DB::raw("($sql order by users.plano_id) a"))
            ->mergeBindings($usuarios->getQuery());

return $res->paginate(25);
```

Código por completo:

```
$usuarios1 = DB::table('users')
    ->join('user_municipios', 'user_municipios.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->join('municipios', 'municipios.id', '=', 'user_municipios.municipio_id')
    ->join('perfis', 'perfis.id', '=', 'users.perfil_id')
    ->select('users.id', 'users.municipio_id', 'users.name', 
             'users.minicurriculo','users.fotoPerfil', 
             'users.plano_id', 'perfis.perfil', 
             'municipios.municipio', 'municipios.uf')
    ->where('user_municipios.municipio_id', '=', $municipio_id);   


$usuarios = DB::table('users')->where('users.municipio_id', '=', $municipio_id)
    ->join('municipios', 'municipios.id', '=', 'users.municipio_id')
    ->join('perfis', 'perfis.id', '=', 'users.perfil_id')
    ->select('users.id', 'users.municipio_id', 'users.name', 
             'users.minicurriculo','users.fotoPerfil', 
             'users.plano_id', 'perfis.perfil', 
             'municipios.municipio', 'municipios.uf')
    ->orderBy('users.plano_id', 'DESC') 
    ->inRandomOrder()
    ->union($usuarios1);

$sql = $usuarios->toSql();
$res = \DB::table(\DB::raw("($sql order by users.plano_id) a"))
            ->mergeBindings($usuarios->getQuery());

return $res->paginate(25);
```

***Observação:*** esse `orderBy` com `inRandomOrder` nunca vai dar certo, ou um ou outro e eu deixei como estava o correto talvez seja feito na `$res` dessa forma:

```
return $res->inRandomOrder()->paginate(25);
```

<sub>***Referencia***</sub>

- [Eloquent - Unions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#unions)

Comment: Não de certo, Virgilio

Comment: @BrunoSantos é para dar certo, qual é o erro?

Comment: @BrunoSantos suas perguntas nunca tem uma interação legal com quem responde, você deixa muitas informações pendentes, "não deu certo" deve ter acontecido algo para que não dê certo, então exponha o erro ou então porque deu errado, a gente quer ajudar você mas, assim fica um pouco difícil espero que compreenda... O Código acima é correto e funcional só que talvez falte alguma coisa que não foi dita!

Comment: no final do código quando tento executar dessa forma: ->union($usuarios1)->get(); ele dar certo, mas quando tento ->paginate(25) no lugar do ->get() da o seguinte erro: QueryException in Connection.php line 647:
QueryException in Connection.php line 647:
SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1222 The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns (SQL: (select count(*) as aggregate from `users` inner join `municipios` on `municipios`.`id` = `users`.`municipio_id` inner join `perfis` on `perfis`.`id` = `users`.`perfil_id` where `users`.`municipio_id` = 306) union (select `users`.

Comment: não consigo colar todo o erro aqui

Comment: Realmente funciona mas preciso usar o ->paginate() lo lugar do ->get()

Comment: Teste o ->simplePaginate(25) e funcionou, mas não consigo com o ->paginate();

Comment: @BrunoSantos eu fiz a edição, tem que ser adequado ao seu ai, mas, tem que ser feito assim, olhe as observação e qualquer problema me avise!